# cant access function parameters in mongoose query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, express, mongoose

I am trying to make a general function to find a model Object in mongoose Models, but its unable to access key from function parameters. Please help

```
    ...
    findInModel: async (Model, key, value) => {
        const modelObj = await Model.fineOne({ key: value });
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a object with key is a variable, you have to use array access style.

```
    findInModel: async (Model, key, value) => {
        const query = {};
        query[key] = value;
        const modelObj = await Model.fineOne(query);
    }
```